# Jquery TimeCircles Value when stopped

Tags: jquery, return-value

this is what I have so far. I would like to be able to remove class hidden from a submit button and then copy the timer value to a hidden text field. Any help would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".timer").TimeCircles({
    "start": false,
    "animation": "smooth",
    "bg_width": 1.2,
    "fg_width": 0.1,
    "circle_bg_color": "#60686F",
    "time": {
        "Days": {
            "text": "Days",
            "color": "#FFCC66",
            "show": false
        },
        "Hours": {
            "text": "Hours",
            "color": "#99CCFF",
            "show": false
        },
        "Minutes": {
            "text": "Minutes",
            "color": "#BBFFBB",
            "show": true
        },
        "Seconds": {
            "text": "Seconds",
            "color": "#FF9999",
            "show": true
        }
    }
  });
  $(".stop").click(function(){
    $(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().stop();
  });
  $(".start").click(function(){
    $(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().start();
    //remove class hidden on submit button
    //copy timer value to text field

  });
  //$(".restart").click(function(){
  //    $(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().restart();
  //}); 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not clear what you're trying to do... when do you want to remove the class from button..? what is `.TimeCircles` ?  are you using a plugin..? Please update the question with proper information...

Comment: TimeCircles is a Jquery Timer/Stopwatch plugin. The author responded with exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it would've probably have helped if you could've included your html, however:

Removing a class from "a submit button" can be done using:

```js
$("[type=submit]").removeClass('hidden');
```

You can get the remaining time using:

```js
var timeleft = $(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().getTime();
```

You can place that value into a textbox using:

```js
$("input#timervalue").val(timeleft);
```

Comment: That what I got after looking around on my own. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Wim. That's almost the same answer that I got. Thsi is what I ended up with.

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
$(".timer").TimeCircles({
    "start": false,
    "animation": "smooth",
    "bg_width": 1.2,
    "fg_width": 0.1,
    "circle_bg_color": "#60686F",
    "time": {
        "Days": {
            "text": "Days",
            "color": "#FFCC66",
            "show": false
        },
        "Hours": {
            "text": "Hours",
            "color": "#99CCFF",
            "show": false
        },
        "Minutes": {
            "text": "Minutes",
            "color": "#BBFFBB",
            "show": true
        },
        "Seconds": {
            "text": "Seconds",
            "color": "#FF9999",
            "show": true
        }
    }
});
$(".stop").click(function(){
    $(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().stop();
    $("#activitysubmit").prop("disabled",false);
    var activity_time = $(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().getTime();
    $("#activity_time").val(Math.abs(activity_time));
    //alert ($(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().getTime());

});
$(".start").click(function(){
    $(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().start();
    $("#activitysubmit").prop("disabled",true);

});
//$(".restart").click(function(){
//  $(".timer.stopwatch").TimeCircles().restart();
//});
```

});